# remove all media query css rules from a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove those css style rules which are applied in media queries from a particular div (including its children too).

For eg.

```
.foo{
  color: red;/*don't remove*/
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .foo{
    background-color: blue;/*remove*/
    font-size: .8em;/*remove*/
  }
  div{
    color: #000;/*don't remove*/
  }
}
```

In the example `.foo` element css of media query should be removed but not css rules outside the media queries.

Comment: Do you not have access to the file with the media queries? What's the purpose of this... can you not just overwrite your styles with !important and/or with combined selectors...

Comment: Maybe using `window.matchMedia()` Start by reading the applied styles during a matched media query and remove them? [Here](http://tylergaw.com/articles/reacting-to-media-queries-in-javascript) is a read demonstrating similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit, Updated

Try (v2)

html

```
<div class="foo">abc123
    <br /> <span>def789</span>
    <br /> <section>ghi456</section>
</div>
```

css

```
.foo{
  color: red;/*don't remove*/
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .foo{
    background-color: blue;/*remove*/
    font-size: .8em;/*remove*/
  }
  div{
    color: #000;/*don't remove*/
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .foo span{
    color: green;/*remove*/
    font-size: 36px;/*remove*/
  }
.foo section{
    color: blue;/*remove*/
    font-size: 48px;/*remove*/
  }
}
```

js

Note, `.foo{color: red;/*don't remove*/}` remains set at `.foo` children ; possible to set other valid value at properties

```
$(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        $("style").text(function (_, o) {
            return o.replace(/\.foo+\{\n+.*\n+.*\n+\s+\}(?=\n\s+div)/g, "")
        });
        $(".foo *").each(function (i, el) {
            el.style.all = "unset"
        })
    }
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/v7LLo7q1/1/

See [unset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) , [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all)

```js
$(function() {
    if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
        $("style").text(function (_, o) {
           return o.replace(/\.foo+\{\n+.*\n+.*\n+\s+\}(?=\n\s+div)/g, "")
        });
        $(".foo *").each(function (i, el) {
            el.style.all = "unset"
        })
    }
})
```

```css
.foo{
  color: red;/*don't remove*/
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .foo{
    background-color: blue;/*remove*/
    font-size: .8em;/*remove*/
  }
  div{
    color: #000;/*don't remove*/
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  .foo span{
    color: green;/*remove*/
    font-size: 36px;/*remove*/
  }
.foo section{
    color: blue;/*remove*/
    font-size: 48px;/*remove*/
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo">abc123
    <br /> <span>def789</span>
    <br /> <section>ghi456</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. This is the answer what I was looking for. Really helpful, plus I want to remove all children media query css, any idea?

Comment: @C-linkNepal You are welcome:) ? Not certain if interpret _all children media query css_ correctly ? If possible , can post `css` of _all children_ ? Thanks

Comment: also to remove all children of .foo media query css

Comment: @C-linkNepal Piece attempts to remove `.foo` within `@media (max-width: 768px){}` . Elements  having class `.foo` should have styles removed , including children of `.foo`. If possible , can post `html` , `css` of `.foo` children ? Thanks

Comment: The children may be anything so all classes and htmls media queries should be removed

Comment: @C-linkNepal Still uncertain about all children case. If possible , can post example ? Thanks

Comment: you're setting initial, I think that also removes the css applied outside the media query???

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. It might help you.

```
function f(){
    var h = document.getElementById("head");
    h.style.removeProperty("color");
}

<body onload="f();">
        <h1 id="head"style="background-color: green; color: red;">Removing a specific style</h1>
</body>
```

If you want to remove the whole style attribute from the tag, try this.

```
document.getElementById("head").removeAttribute("style");
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting inline styles with jQuery's `css()` method will overwrite the attributes within a media query.

```
function setStyles() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 768){  
        $('.foo').css({
            'background': 'none',
            'font-size': '1em'
        });
    } else {
        $('.foo').css({
            'background': '',
            'font-size': ''
        });
    }
}

setStyles();

$(window).resize(setStyles);
```

Reproduce the media query using `resize()` and a `if width` block to set new styles.

Use the `else` block to remove the inline styles, resulting back to your stylesheet attributes.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/43f71x0x/2/)

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if I understood the question, but let me know if this is what you want?

```css
.foo{
  color: red;/*don't remove*/
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
  div{
    color: #000;/*don't remove*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">some text</div>
```

Comment: -1, Sorry Im pretty sure the OP doesn't need you to *remove* the code for him.

Comment: Sure, just trying to understand the question properly

Comment: @TiagoMoreira I want to remove those css from javascript or jquery.

Comment: Understandable, do so in the comments of the question not as an answer.